# MySQL Query for Team Schedule

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve schedules for each team based on my table below, but I am having some trouble getting the team names to display. Here are my tables:

TEAM
(team_id, 
team_name, 
team_mascot, 
etc.)

GAME
(game_id, 
game_date, 
game_home_team, 
game_visitor_team, 
game_home_score, 
game_visitor_score, 
game_complete)

Here is my current query. I am able to get the team's id values with this but I need the team names as id values won't do me much good.

```
SELECT game_home_team, game_visitor_team, game_date
FROM game 
INNER JOIN team home ON home.team_id = game_home_team 
INNER JOIN team visitor ON visitor.team_id = game_visitor_team
WHERE game_home_team = ? 
OR game_visitor_team = 6 
ORDER BY game_date ASC;
```

How can I retrieve the team names with this query and also display a result such as W or L depending on the score for the game? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Which team do you want the w and l for, the visitor or home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
   home.team_name AS home_team,
   visitor.team_name AS visitor_team,
   game_date,
   IF(
      game_home_score = game_visitor_score, 
      'Tie', 
      IF(
         game_home_score > game_visitor_score,
         'Hometeam',
         'Visitorteam'
      )
   ) AS Winner
FROM game 
INNER JOIN team home ON home.team_id = game_home_team 
INNER JOIN team visitor ON visitor.team_id = game_visitor_team
WHERE game_home_team = ? 
OR game_visitor_team = 6 
ORDER BY game_date ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. The problem I am having now is that both home_team and visitor_team are showing as the same.

Comment: @RCM8402 if you pleased with an answer here at SO, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that answer, see that you havn't accepted any answers on any of your questions so far

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I had to accept the answer. Thanks for letting me know and thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select game_home_team, home.team_name AS homename,
    game_visitor_team, visitor.team_name AS visitorname
etc...
```